# How to get particular values from xml tags in android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

```
<dict>
<key>Finance</key>
<dict>
<key>MainContent</key>
<array><string>Transactions</string><string>Booking Sales</string><string>Export Booking</string><string>Operation Revenue</string></array></dict>
<key>AboutUs</key>
<dict>
<key>MenuItems</key>
<array><dict><key>name</key><string>Ship Owning</string><key>submenu</key><array><string>Orient Express Lines FZCO</string><string>Transworld Bulk Carriers FZCO</string></array>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>name</key>
<string>Feeder</string>
<key>submenu</key>
<array><string>Orient Express Lines FZCO</string><string>Shreyas Shipping And Logistics Ltd</string></array>
</dict>
</dict>
```

In above xml file how to get `<string>` tag values.
Is there any best efficient way to get values.

Comment: just a heads up but I'm 90% sure that isn't valid XML. On line 9 there are two `<array>` tags opened but 1 isnt closed, and there seems to be mismatched tags with the `<dict>` elements too,

Comment: I given just for question. tell me just how read values from <string>  tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get very far if your xml isn't well formed. You can use a library such as JSoup to attempt to clean up the xml.

See here: http://try.jsoup.org/~qw0Vw1_TiKI71RmfxOn9HPL8u1U

Then its a case of just using the library to clean the xml, and tell it to pick out the info you want:

```
package doodle;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = Jsoup
                .parse("<dict><key>Finance</key><dict><key>MainContent</key><array><string>Transactions</string><string>Booking Sales</string><string>Export Booking</string><string>Operation Revenue</string></array></dict><key>AboutUs</key><dict><key>MenuItems</key><array><dict><key>name</key><string>Ship Owning</string><key>submenu</key><array><string>Orient Express Lines FZCO</string><string>Transworld Bulk Carriers FZCO</string></array></dict><dict><key>name</key><string>Feeder</string><key>submenu</key><array><string>Orient Express Lines FZCO</string><string>Shreyas Shipping And Logistics Ltd</string></array></dict></dict>");

        Elements elements = doc.select("string");

        for (Element element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element.text());
        }

    }

}
```

`Transactions
Booking Sales
Export Booking
Operation Revenue
Ship Owning
Orient Express Lines FZCO
Transworld Bulk Carriers FZCO
Feeder
Orient Express Lines FZCO
Shreyas Shipping And Logistics Ltd`

Comment: thks. If i want to get only Ship Owning and sub menu means

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your asking. In any case, you can be more specific with regards to what is extracted. Look here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation